C language, function parameter value passing error
I have been studying the Linux 0.11 source code recently and debugging it. In the experiment, I needed to print process messages when a process exits. Therefore, I added the fprintk function in /kernel/printk.c as shown below:
// static char logbuf[1024];
int fprintk(int fd)
{
    printk("--------------------------------------\n");
    printk("fprintk called with fd: %d\n", fd);  // Debugging information
    // va_list args;
    // int count;
    // va_start(args, fmt);
    // count = vsprintf(logbuf, fmt, args);
    // va_end(args);
    // printk("fprintk: formatted string: %s\n", logbuf);  // Debugging information
    // if (fd == 3) {
    //  count = sys_write(fd, logbuf, count);
    //  printk("fprintk: written %d bytes to fd %d\n", count, fd);  // Debugging information
    // }
    printk("--------------------------------------\n");
    // return count;
    return 0;
}

Then, I added the function call in the do_exit() function of /kernel/exit.c:
int fd = 3;
......
printk("exit fd: %d\n", fd);
// fprintk(fd, "%ld\t%c\t%ld\n", current->pid, 'E', jiffies);
fprintk(fd);
...

do_exit code:
int do_exit(long code)
{
    int i;
    int fd = 3;
    free_page_tables(get_base(current->ldt[1]),get_limit(0x0f));
    free_page_tables(get_base(current->ldt[2]),get_limit(0x17));
    for (i=0 ; i<NR_TASKS ; i++)
        if (task[i] && task[i]->father == current->pid) {
            task[i]->father = 1;
            if (task[i]->state == TASK_ZOMBIE)
                /* assumption task[1] is always init */
                (void) send_sig(SIGCHLD, task[1], 1);
        }
    for (i=0 ; i<NR_OPEN ; i++)
        if (current->filp[i])
            sys_close(i);
    iput(current->pwd);
    current->pwd=NULL;
    iput(current->root);
    current->root=NULL;
    iput(current->executable);
    current->executable=NULL;
    if (current->leader && current->tty >= 0)
        tty_table[current->tty].pgrp = 0;
    if (last_task_used_math == current)
        last_task_used_math = NULL;
    if (current->leader)
        kill_session();
    current->state = TASK_ZOMBIE;
    current->exit_code = code;
    // before father wakes up, children exits
    printk("exit fd: %d\n", fd);
    // fprintk(fd, "%ld\t%c\t%ld\n", current->pid, 'E', jiffies);
    fprintk(fd);
    tell_father(current->father);
    schedule();
    return (-1);    /* just to suppress warnings */
}

In the actual experiment, I found that the printed fd is not 3, but a very strange value, and I don't know why, I'll appreciate it very much if you can give some adivices.


If it's a "strange value", your program might have undefined behavior somewhere prior to the function call. Show all your code in context.

as the image above, when I call fprintk function, the value of fd is 3, there is nothing between the two line code

do_exit tends to be special. Maybe you should edit your question and post your full modified version of do_exit. And, [obviously] version 0.11 is a bit hard to come by, so posting the version you're working on would save some time.

okk, the do_exit has been shown above

What are you running this on? (e.g. qemu with a [bochs] debugger)? I'd put a breakpoint on the call to fprintk in do_exit. Then, I'd single step the asm instructions and look a registers. A disassembly of fprintk would show where it expects the arg to be placed (i.e. where on the stack or which register). You could also disassemble the code near the call and ensure that the calling conventions match up. (The disassembly could be done statically on your development system).

Although there's plenty of code beween the int fd = 3; and the call, the printk you do shows that it's intact [mostly]. So, this leaves the call to fprintk itself. Does the prototype that do_exit sees for fprintk (in a .h file) match the function definition (assuming fprintk is in a different .c file)? You could try compiling the files with the two functions do_exit and fprintk with -O0 and see if that changes anything. And, comment out the printk("---------\n"); lines so that only the one remains in fprintk.

How did you rebuild the kernel after making your changes?  IIRC, Linux on x86-32 uses compiler flags that specify a non-standard calling convention (-mregparm I believe).  So if exit.c and printk.c didn't get compiled with the same option, you'd see fprintk receive the wrong arguments.  I don't think the non-standard conventions apply to variadic functions, which would also explain why printk itself still works.

Thank you very much! I have tried compiling the files with the two functions do_exit and fprintk with -O0, then the result is correct! But I still don't understand, so strange
